# how-to-horizontally-slide-views

Tags: android, view

I had to create a list view with image and text items, when i click on a item it should navigate to detail view, which is web view contains image with some information. How to slide to the next details view with out going back to the list view. i tried this  [post](http://www.codeshogun.com/blog/2009/04/16/how-to-implement-swipe-action-in-android/) . But i need to show details dynamically in one web view.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a method called
>   `CreateWebView();` and do all your
>   dynamic loading part in that. Whenever
>   slide left or slide right event occurs
>   call the `CreateWebView();` method with
>   proper parameters to identify previous
>   or next.